# Fitting map bounds to raster layer

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I've ran across all `fitbounds` tutorials for Mapbox and still cannot figure out how refocus my map on a given raster layer. I have a menu that toggles a number of older maps and would like to refit the map at each turn.

Here's what I have so far. `mapnumber` is the string for my raster map.

```
      var coordinates = map.getBounds(mapnumber);
      var bounds = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(coordinates[0], coordinates[0]);
      map.fitBounds({bounds});
```

The bounds are there, I just cannot use fitbounds on them. This is the error.

```
lng_lat.js:97 Uncaught Error: `LngLatLike` argument must be specified 
as a LngLat instance, an object {lng: <lng>, lat: <lat>}, or an array 
of [<lng>, <lat>]
```

Comment: Try `map.fitBounds(bounds);` without the {} brackets

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Uncaught Error: `LngLatLike` argument must be specified 
>   as a LngLat instance

It looks like you're using mapboxgl.LngLatBounds incorrectly. You'll need to pass in two LngLat instances, rather than two coordinates. The [API docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglatbounds) have an example that creates a point for the southwest and northeast corners of your bounding box:

```
var sw = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-73.9876, 40.7661);
var ne = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-73.9397, 40.8002);
var llb = new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(sw, ne);
```

Then you can use `map.fitBounds()` with the bounding box

```
map.fitBounds(llb);
```

**UPDATE: answering follow up question**

> how can I extract the two sets (sw and ne) from the raster?

You can use the [`map.getSource()` method](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#getsource). Pass in the source ID of your raster layer and that will return an object that has a `bounds` property. Use this bounds property to pass into `map.fitBounds()`.

```
var bounds = map.getSource('mapbox://username.source-id').bounds;
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/mapsam/pen/RZvyBQ

Comment: Thank you! I also assumed this was the case, however, how can I extract the two sets (sw and ne) from the raster? I know it has them, but using `coordinates[0]` doesn't work. The raster file is hosted by Mapbox.

Comment: great question @east1999! I've updated the answer above pointing out how to use `map.getSource()` to retrieve the bounds for your raster layer.

Comment: Coming back to this, I just wanted to thank you for your answer and for your amazing and inspiring work with Mapbox. As an FYI, although I marked the question as resolved, it's a little bit more complicated. The mapname is pulled dynamically using a javascript function (needed this for building a menu), so I'm not yet sure how to combine that with getSource. Can I use the layer's name to get its source id? Side question, but again, thank you!